# Text Next to Styled Radio Button

Tags: css, radio-button

I've customised my radio buttons with the help of [this](http://www.paulund.co.uk/style-checkboxes-with-css) tutorial.

Now I'm trying to add text next to the radio buttons but I can't really figure it out with this structure I've got.

Any ideas?

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
<div class="radioButton">
    <input type="radio" name="x" value="y" id="y" />
    <label for="y"></label>
</div>

<div class="radioButton">
    <input type="radio" name="x" value="z" id="z" />
    <label for="z"></label>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type=radio] {
  visibility: visible; }

.radioButton {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #dedede;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative; }

/* Create the radio button */
.radioButton label {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white; }

/* Radio button checked state */
.radioButton input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background: #77a942; }

/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the text inside the label and using CSS to indent it

```
.radioButton label{
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a better implementation using CSS's `:before` pseudo-element

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Pb9/4/)**

```
input[type=radio] {
    visibility: visible;
}
.radioButton {
    height: 22px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    position: relative;
}
.radioButton label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}
/* Create the radio button */
 .radioButton label:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    border: solid 2px #ddd;
}
/* Radio button checked state */
 .radioButton input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    background: #77a942;
}
```

Comment: @CanSürmeli No problem, I updated with a new implementation that seems better to me though

Comment: @CanSürmeli It fixes an issue with using text-indent where the text wouldn't wrap nicely, also it provides better semantics since the label is not used to create the stylized checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Add a div after the radioButton div with your text.  This isn't optimal, because the control has highjacked the label, so you can't click on this text and have the control be clicked (unless you add javascript to do that), but it'll look right. http://jsfiddle.net/MdAEG/

```
<fieldset>
<div class="radioButton">
    <input type="radio" name="x" value="y" id="y" />
    <label for="y"></label>
</div> 
<div class="radioLabel">Hi there</div>

<div class="radioButton">
    <input type="radio" name="x" value="z" id="z" />
    <label for="z"></label>
</div>
<div class="radioLabel">Howdy</div>    
</fieldset>

input[type=radio] {
  visibility: visible; }

.radioLabel {
    float: left;
    clear:right;
    margin: 22px 5px;
}
.radioButton {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #dedede;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
   float: left;
    clear: left;
}

/* Create the radio button */
.radioButton label {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white; }


/* Radio button checked state */
.radioButton input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background: #77a942; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following CSS

```
label{
    padding-left: 23px;
}
```

Then add some text to your label

```
<label for="z">Label here</label>
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/z9Pb9/

Comment: That's not going to work.  The css steals the label for it's green circle.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird is right. 'label' is used for the radio button's checked state to appear green. Your technique expands the checked state. Thanks for your effort anyway. :)